# Can I use my oven without a light bulb cover?

Tags: repair, oven

I was trying to replace the light bulb in my oven. When I removed the light bulb cover (made of very thick glass)I dropped it and it broke. My question is..can I use my oven without a light bulb cover over the light bulb ?

Comment: Seems like the missing cover might let hot air out of the oven and possibly overheat whatever was near the cover, but I don't know enough to be sure.  Is the cover on the back of the oven?  Make/Model?

Comment: Yes it is on the back wall. It is a Kennmore Elite Will look for model number

Comment: Restating another answer : With no glass cover some hot air will escape and likely do bad things to any electrical components in the area . The bulb , per se , is not the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The bulb, if it is rated to be used in an oven, will function without a glass cover. The reason for the tempered glass cover is to protect the bulb from damage due to pans and trays and also it keeps it clean from hot liquids. To save yourself the hassle and expense for replacing the bulbs it would be wise to order a replacement cover.

Answer (score 0):

I have had my Bosch oven (mdl HBL 3350UC) 10+ years. The oven Lens cover has broken three times, probably due to high heat used when baking bread. I have replace the lens -$30 each time.  I know use the oven with no cover and the bulb works fine.  I expected more from Bosch. This is poor engineering. When the cover explodes, glass gets into the food. But you are not aware of this, because there is no loud noise (or I am not sitting next to the oven when this occurs).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.